# select null within a select statement in SP when date is 01-01-1900

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored Procedure is as follows. In my table of sales_order there is a date column `CP_Created_On`. In table for some lines date I have inserted as `01-01-1900`. Now I am selecting records from the table. I want to select `NULL` when date for some rows is `01-01-1900`. I want it in this fashion because I am exporting the records to an excel via a `DATASET`. Please help

Thanks.

set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sale_OrderPlan_View_Excel_test] --'EM00164466'
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(
    @SO_AM varchar(30)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

declare @Cnt int
CREATE TABLE #Tab
(SYNC_BY VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #Tab
(SYNC_BY)
select SYNC_BY from dbo.SYNC_Master where 
MONTH(SYNC_Last_Sync_Date)=MONTH(GETDATE()) and YEAR(SYNC_Last_Sync_Date)=YEAR(GETDATE())

set @Cnt=(select count(*) from #Tab)
drop table #Tab

-- ACCEPTING INPUT AS "title_code" HAVING VALUE (-1)

            SELECT  SO_Code as 'Form10 Code',
                    SO_ProfitCentre as'Profit Centre',
--                  SO_DivCode as 'SO_DivCode',
                    SO_SalesOffice as 'Sales Office',
                    SO_F_Customer as 'F-Customer Code',
                    SO_CustName as 'F-Customer Name',
                    SO_L_Customer as 'L-Customer',
                    SO_RefDoc       as 'Ref Doc',
                    SO_invoiceNo        as 'Invoice No',
                    SO_DocType      as 'Doc Type',
                    SO_DocDesc      as 'Doc Desc',
                    SO_AccDocNo     as 'Acc Doc No',
--                  SO_SplGLindicator   as 'Spl GL indicator',
                    SO_SplGLDesc        as 'Spl GL Desc',
                    convert(varchar,SO_DocDate,105) as 'Doc Date',
                    SO_OutstandingAmt   as 'Outstanding Amt',
                    SO_CreditBal        as 'Credit Balance',
                    SO_PureAdvances as 'Pure Advances',
                    SO_UnadjustableCrBal as 'Uneducable Cr Bal',
                    convert(varchar,SO_BaseDate,105) as 'Base Date',
                    SO_LegacyInvoiceRef as 'Legacy Invoice Ref',
                    SO_WBS  as 'WBS',
                    tbl_Region_Master.REGIONNAME as 'Region',
                    tbl_Branch_Master.BRANCHNAME as 'Branch',
                    dbo.TBL_DIVISIONGROUP.GROUPNAME as 'Div Group',
                    SO_SubDiv       as 'Sub Div',
                    SO_OrderType        as 'Order Type',
                    SO_Usage            as 'Usage',
                    SO_AgeInDays        as 'Age In Days',
                    SO_LYCY         as 'LY/CY',
                    convert(varchar,SO_invoiceDt,105) as 'Invoice Date',
                    SO_InvoiceAmt   as 'Invoice Amt',
                    SO_SalesOrderNO     as 'Sales Order NO',
                    SO_OrderValue as 'Order Value',
                    SO_PoNo as 'Po No',
                    convert(varchar,SO_PoDate,105) as 'Po Date',
                    Dl.NAME1+' '+Dl.NAME2   as 'Dealer Associate',
                    SO_Write_Off as 'Write Off',
                    SO_Adjustments as 'Adjustments',
                    SO_CreditNote as 'CreditNote',
                    SO_OtherDeduction as 'Other Deduction',
                    SO_TDS as 'TDS',
                    SO_NetCollectable as 'NetCollectable',
                    SO_CurrentMnth as 'Current Month',
                    SO_NextMnth     as 'Next Month',
                    SO_NexttoNextMnth as 'Next to Next Month',
                    E1.NAME1+' '+E1.NAME2   as 'SDE',
                    tbl_EmpMaster.NAME1+' '+tbl_EmpMaster.NAME2 as 'SME',
                    E2.NAME1+' '+E2.NAME2   as 'AM',
                    E3.NAME1+' '+E3.NAME2       as 'RM',
                    E4.NAME1+' '+E4.NAME2   as 'AIH',
                    E5.NAME1+' '+E5.NAME2   as 'COMEXE',
                    SO_BUSFIN   as 'BUSFIN',            
                    SO_CF as 'CF',                  
                    SO_PlanCode as 'Plan Code',
                    SO_WriteOff_Reason as 'WriteOff Reason',
                    SO_Adjustments_Reason as 'Adjustments Reason',
                    SO_CreditNote_Reason as 'CreditNote Reason',
                    SO_OtherDeduction_Reason as 'Other Deduction Reason',
                    convert(varchar,CP_Created_On,105) as 'Created On',
                    E7.NAME1+' '+E7.NAME2 as 'Approved By'

            FROM dbo.tbl_Sale_Order
            left join dbo.tbl_Region_Master on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_Region=dbo.tbl_Region_Master.REGION_ID
            left join dbo.tbl_Branch_Master on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_Branch=dbo.tbl_Branch_Master.SALES_BRANCH_CODE
            left join dbo.TBL_DIVISIONGROUP on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_DivGroup=dbo.TBL_DIVISIONGROUP.GROUPCODE
            left join dbo.tbl_EmpMaster E1 on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_SDE=E1.PORTALUSERNAME
            left join tbl_EmpMaster on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_SME=tbl_EmpMaster.PORTALUSERNAME
            left join tbl_EmpMaster E2 on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_AM=E2.PORTALUSERNAME
            left join tbl_EmpMaster E3 on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_RM=E3.PORTALUSERNAME
            left join tbl_EmpMaster E4 on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_AIH=E4.PORTALUSERNAME
            left join tbl_EmpMaster E5 on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_COMEXE=E5.PORTALUSERNAME
--          left join tbl_EmpMaster E6 on tbl_Sale_Order.CP_Created_By=E6.PORTALUSERNAME
            left join tbl_EmpMaster E7 on tbl_Sale_Order.Approved_By=E7.PORTALUSERNAME
            left join dbo.tbl_Dealer_Master Dl on tbl_Sale_Order.SO_Dealer_Associate=Dl.DEALERCODE
            WHERE
                tbl_Sale_Order.SO_AM=@SO_AM and SO_OutstandingAmt>0 and SO_CreditBal=0 and @Cnt>0 and month(Creation_date)=Month(getdate()) and year(Creation_date)=year(getdate())


END
```

Comment: Google "Select case when", i think thats what you need

Comment: I tried doing that but it is not helping. This is what I am writing

case  
     when CP_Created_On =01-01-1900 
     then ''
     when CP_Created_On !=01-01-1900
     then  CP_Created_On
           end as 'Created On' ,

Comment: You must wrap the date into proper sql date. I'm not behind a computer now, but i don't think your syntax is right. (Case when else), but i see others are helping out with syntax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN cp_created_on = '19000101' THEN NULL 
         ELSE cp_created_on 
       END AS CP_Created_On 
FROM   dbo.TableName
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a891/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

[NullIF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) is your friend here!

```
DECLARE @d date = '1900-01-01';

SELECT @d As d
     , NullIf(@d, '1900-01-01')
     , NullIf(Current_Timestamp, '1900-01-01')
```